# DataBodyRange copy when table (filtered) is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have database (excel table) with answers from which I need copy comments to other sheet. For each question answers are in different columns. Currently I have code that work properly if there are answers. But if there is not it returns whole database.

So after some research i've tried If DataBodyRange Is Nothing but it looks like code is ignored. Results are the same as without this line.

```
Sub Filter_Comments()

Dept = "Science"
WS = "Comments"

'1st question comments
Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A7").Value
Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Dept
Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
If Not Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange.Copy
    Worksheets(WS).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Copy
    Worksheets(WS).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter
End If

'2st question comments
Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A7").Value
Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Dept
Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
If Not Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange.Copy
    Worksheets(WS).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(10).DataBodyRange.Copy
    Worksheets(WS).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter
End If

End Sub
```

So, currently it works fine if there are comments, but not if filtered table is empty.

The goal is to have all comments one by one in rows.
Could You please help with walking around the empty table after filtering?

Best,
Wiktor

Comment: You tried If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange) >0 Then "do something as not empty..."  Else ........

Comment: As far as my tests shows, DataBodyRange is always the full table body range, even when filtered.

Comment: I've tried Applications.WorksheetFunction.... but unfortunately after change it doesn't copy anything, even if there are comments.